# After update Android SDK platfrom-tools 24 "Could not find method apt()" why?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

After update  Android  SDK platfrom-tools 24 occur this error :

> Could not find method apt() for arguments
>   [com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1] on
>   DefaultExternalModuleDependency{g
>       roup='com.android.support', name='appcompat-v7', version='24.0.0', configuration='default'}.

Top level  build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Project dependencies :

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

def _androidSupport = "24.0.0"
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.8@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:2.2.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${_androidSupport}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${_androidSupport}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:24.0.0:${_androidSupport}"

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependencies block should include *both* of the following two lines:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)